# PhoneGap Build: Admob Ads (Remove Test Ad with Legit Ads)

Tags: android, cordova, admob, phonegap-build, phonegap-admob

I know how to get ads up and running thanks to this Github repo - https://github.com/appfeel/admob-phonegap-build-demo

I'm already aware of the AdMob policy - https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en_US

> It is against AdMob policy to click on your own live ads. During
>   development and testing, use test ads. If you do need to render live
>   ads before launch, avoid clicking on them. If you click on live ads,
>   your AdMob account may be suspended.

However I replaced the ad unit ID's from the id's in the repo with mine from Google Admob and I'm still getting the test ads.

Before I release my app I want to make sure that official ads are up and working fine without test ads. (Users would pay for a pro version that doesn't contain any ads).

How can I get official ads displayed and not test ads?

Comment: It takes often sometime for the ads to show up..And as we are working with the web-view i have seen that the web-view is cached..So one thing you can do is force close you app..remove app cache and try again..More here  pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-banner-ads-to-phonegap-apps-using-admob-pro-plugin/

Comment: The link doesn't work. I get what you're saying though. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: here is the link..It works now http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-interstitial-ads-on-navigation-for-phonegap-app-using-admob/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin author here. Normally if your admob account is approved, the real ads should start to show (or no ads will be shown if Admob can't serve ads to your app). You could also create your own campaign and use it in the admob mediation to check that the ads are being served.

Maybe an obvious question: Have you replaced `isTesting: true` by `isTesting: false`? No test ads should be shown in any case when `isTesting: false`.

https://github.com/appfeel/admob-phonegap-build-demo/blob/master/www/js/index.js#L74

Comment: Finally had some free time to look over the code, and yep I had `isTesting` set to `true`. Thanks!